# Blob request in different language

Tags: javascript, blob

Im trying to use a private API and i have a problem im unable to solve. The JavaScript code im trying to recreate is

```
XMLHttpRequest.send(blob);
```

Blob has the type: "image/jpeg" and a size.
The blob is created from a html input.
Im relativly new to JavaScript and web development so please excuse if this is unclear.
My question is how to recreate this request in any other language preferably Java, Python or NodeJS. As far as i know is blob just a large binary object but i cant find any information how to create a blob like object in any other language.
I hope this question is kind of clear.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to create the blob in java ?

Comment: My only goal is to send the same request like the code above does using a different language

Comment: Send from where? The blob being created from the user input is a fundamental part of the code you've described. Please show your actual use case created with that other language, and specify an accurate language too.

Comment: _“My only goal is to send the same request like the code above does”_ - then start perhaps by finding out what the actual request caused by this looks like, using your browser dev tools? There’s probably not much “magic” going on in the first place, likely this just figures out the appropriate `Content-Type` header to set, and then just puts the actual binary image data into the request body …

Comment: OK lets say python. I got an image file and i want to send this image with the python requests package in a way that the final packe send by my computer is the same as if i would send it from the website that creates this request with the code above. Im sorry for the bad descrition of my problem

Comment: @misorude i already did this and the content type is like the blob "image/jpeg" its probably easy to solve but the only part im unable to recreate is the request payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js You could do the following, There is no blob in node.js, you can Buffer instead of blob.

Please check this out.

```js
let imageData = imageFile.toString('base64')
let data = Buffer.from(imageData, 'base64');

var post_options = {
      host: '<domain>',
      path: '<path>',
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
      }
  };

  // Set up the request
  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    // handle response
  });
```

Comment: Please make sure Ur importing Buffer module

Comment: @Jerry   It's depends on Ur usecase, here I have sent only content length. Just thought of presenting the usecase. I've updated my code to send the data as well. Please check now